# About jboss-cli user authentication

Tags: jboss

I changed the name of the jboss home directory. By the way, jboss-cli user authentication didn't come out before changing the name, but user authentication comes out after changing it, what should I do?

Set jboss-home environment variables

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.